# Why does setting triggers for CodeDeploy deployment group fail with InvalidTriggerConfigException?

Tags: amazon-web-services, triggers, aws-cli, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to set up triggers with awc cli.
According to documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-notify-edit.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateDeploymentGroup.html

```
aws deploy update-deployment-group --application-name NAME --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime --current-deployment-group-name TEST --trigger-configurations '[{"triggerName":"TEST-CD","triggerTargetArn":"my:arn","triggerEvents":["DEPLOYMENT_SUCCESS|DEPLOYMENT_FAILURE|INSTANCE_FAILURE"]}]'

aws deploy update-deployment-group --application-name NAME --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime --current-deployment-group-name TEST --trigger-configurations '[{"triggerName":"TEST-CD","triggerTargetArn":"my:arn","triggerEvents":["DEPLOYMENT_SUCCESS"]}]'

aws deploy update-deployment-group --application-name NAME --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime --current-deployment-group-name TEST --trigger-configurations '[{"triggerName":"TEST-CD","triggerTargetArn":"my:arn","triggerEvents":{"DEPLOYMENT_SUCCESS"}}]'
```

But i'm not able to do this. Reciving following errors:

> A client error (InvalidTriggerConfigException) occurred when calling
>   the UpdateDeploymentGroup operation: Invalid Trigger event type

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it properly:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=228103